# Converting Pixels to LatLng Coordinates from google static image

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am loading a image from [google static Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro), the loaded satellite image is a place with hundreds of meters wide and length.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.4055429,-2.9976502&zoom=16&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Additionally, the image resolution shows to be 10 meters, as shown below

[image].

[image]

My question is

as I have known the centered geolocation `(53.4055429,-2.9976502)` and resolution of this static image, how would I be able to extend it to calculate the geolocation of left up or right bottom in the image,  and finally calculate each pixel of the image

Comment: Yes the coordinates following the `center=` parameter are the center of the map (`center=53.4055429,-2.9976502`).  Why do you think they aren't?

Comment: just to confirm it .  how would I get the coordinate of each pixel , would it be possible

Comment: Would it have to be the static maps? The CanvasProjection of the JavaScript API has something that converts pixel locations to lat/lng https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapCanvasProjection

Comment: You can try my answer. Actually you don't need to have google maps js api to do simple math like powers and cosines. Notice, that the two answers have the same results in output console.

Comment: You should select the best answer, otherwise your bounty will disappear in vain.

Answer (score 16):

**What kind of solution is it**

Looks like you need not a javascript solution but for python to use it not in browser but on a server. I've created a python example, but it is the math that I am going to stand on, math is all you need to calculate coordinates. Let me do it with js as well to make snippet work in browser. You can see, that python and js give the same results.

**Jump to the answer**

If you just need formulae for degrees per pixel, here you are. They are simple enough and you don't need any external libraries but just a python's `math`. The explanation can be found further.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

w = 400
h = 400
zoom = 16
lat = 53.4055429
lng = -2.9976502

def getPointLatLng(x, y):
    parallelMultiplier = math.cos(lat * math.pi / 180)
    degreesPerPixelX = 360 / math.pow(2, zoom + 8)
    degreesPerPixelY = 360 / math.pow(2, zoom + 8) * parallelMultiplier
    pointLat = lat - degreesPerPixelY * ( y - h / 2)
    pointLng = lng + degreesPerPixelX * ( x  - w / 2)

    return (pointLat, pointLng)

print 'NE: ', getPointLatLng(w, 0)
print 'SW: ', getPointLatLng(0, h)
print 'NW: ', getPointLatLng(0, 0)
print 'SE: ', getPointLatLng(w, h)
```

The output of [the script](https://github.com/shukshin-ivan/image-coordinates.py) is

```
$ python getcoords.py
NE:  (53.40810128625675, -2.9933586655761717)
SW:  (53.40298451374325, -3.001941734423828)
NW:  (53.40810128625675, -3.001941734423828)
SE:  (53.40298451374325, -2.9933586655761717)
```

**What we have to start with**

We have some parameters needed in url `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.4055429,-2.9976502&zoom=16&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=YOUR_API_KEY` – coordinates, zoom, size in pixels.

Let's introduce some initial variables:

```
var config = {
    lat: 53.4055429,
    lng: -2.9976502,
    zoom: 16,
    size: {
        x: 400,
        y: 400,
    }
};
```

**The math of the Earth of 512 pixels**

The math is as follows. Zoom `1` stands for full view of the Earth equator `360°` when using image size `512` ([see the docs for size and zoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?csw=1#MapCoordinates)). See the [example at zoom 1](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=1&size=512x512&maptype=satellite). It is a very important point. The scale (degrees per pixel) doesn't depend on the image size. When one changes image size, one sees the same scale: compare [1](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.4055429,-2.9976502&zoom=16&size=640x640&maptype=satellite) and [2](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.4055429,-2.9976502&zoom=16&size=400x400&maptype=satellite) – the second image is a cropped version of the bigger one. The maximum image size for `googleapis` is `640`.

Every zoom-in [increases resolution twice](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/hDRO4oHVSeM). Therefore the width of your image in terms of longitude is

```
lngDegrees = 360 / 2**(zoom - 1); // full image width in degrees, ** for power
```

Then use linear function to find coordinates for any point of the image. It should be mentioned, that linearity works well only for high zoomed images, you can't use it for low zooms like 5 or less. Low zooms have slightly more complex math.

```
lngDegreesPerPixel = lngDegrees / 512 = 360 / 2**(zoom - 1) / 2**9 = 360 / 2**(zoom + 8); 
lngX = config.lng + lngDegreesPerPixel * ( point.x - config.size.x / 2);
```

**Latitude degrees are different**

Latitude degree and longitude degree on the equator are of the same size, but if we go north or south, longitude degree become smaller since rings of parallels on the Earth have smaller radii - `r = R * cos(lat) < R` and therefore image height in degrees becomes smaller (see P.S.).

```
latDegrees = 360 / 2**(zoom - 1) * cos(lat); // full image height in degrees, ** for power
```

And respectively

```
latDegreesPerPixel = latDegrees / 512 = 360 / 2**(zoom - 1) * cos(lat) / 2**9 = 360 / 2**(zoom + 8) * cos(lat);
latY = config.lat - latDegreesPerPixel * ( point.y - config.size.y / 2)
```

The sign after `config.lat` differs from the sign for `lngX` since earth longitude direction coincide with image `x` direction, but latitude direction is opposed to `y` direction on the image.

So we can make a simple function now to find a pixel's coordinates using its `x` and `y` coordinates on the picture.

```js
var config = {
    lat: 53.4055429,
    lng: -2.9976502,
    zoom: 16,
    size: {
        x: 400,
        y: 400,
    }
};

function getCoordinates(x, y) {
    var degreesPerPixelX = 360 / Math.pow(2, config.zoom + 8);
    var degreesPerPixelY = 360 / Math.pow(2, config.zoom + 8) * Math.cos(config.lat * Math.PI / 180);

    return {
        lat: config.lat - degreesPerPixelY * ( y - config.size.y / 2),
        lng: config.lng + degreesPerPixelX * ( x  - config.size.x / 2),
    };
}

console.log('SW', getCoordinates(0, config.size.y));
console.log('NE', getCoordinates(config.size.x, 0));
console.log('SE', getCoordinates(config.size.x, config.size.y));
console.log('NW', getCoordinates(0, 0));
console.log('Something at 300,128', getCoordinates(300, 128));
```

P.S. You can probably ask me, why I place `cos(lat)` multiplier to latitude, not as a divider to longitude formula. I found, that google chooses to have constant longitude scale per pixel on different latitudes, so, `cos` goes to latitude as a multiplier.

Comment: This formulae are for top left corner of a pixel. Add `0.5` to parameters of the function to get results for centers of pixels.

Comment: I am using the above formula to calculate the Point/(x,y) for any given coordinate but no luck.

Comment: Point getPointFromCoordinates(double lat,
                                  double lng) {
        double degreesPerPixelX = 360.0 / Math.pow(2, zoom + 8);
        double degreesPerPixelY = 360.0 / Math.pow(2, zoom + 8) * Math.cos(centerLat * Math.PI / 180.0);

        Point point = new Point();

        point.y = (int) ((centerLat - lat) / degreesPerPixelY) + (size.y / 2);
        point.x = (int) ((centerLng - lng) / degreesPerPixelX) + (size.x / 2);

        return point;
    }

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can calculate a bounding box using Maps JavaScript API.

You have a center position and know that distance from the center to the NorthEast and SouthWest is 200 pixels, because the size in your example is 400x400.

Have a look at the following code that calculates NE and SW points

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.4055429,-2.9976502);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
      //Verical and horizontal distance from center in pixels
      var h = 200;
      var w = 200;

      var centerPixel = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
      var pixelSize = Math.pow(2, -map.getZoom());

      var nePoint = new google.maps.Point(centerPixel.x + w*pixelSize, centerPixel.y - h*pixelSize);
      var swPoint = new google.maps.Point(centerPixel.x - w*pixelSize, centerPixel.y + h*pixelSize);

      var ne = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(nePoint);
      var sw = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(swPoint);

      var neMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ne,
        map: map,
        title: "NE: " + ne.toString()
      });

      var swMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: sw,
        map: map,
        title: "SW: " + sw.toString()
      });

      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: [ne, new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(),sw.lng()), sw, new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(),ne.lng())],
          map: map, 
          strokeColor: "green"
      });

      console.log("NE: " + ne.toString());
      console.log("SW: " + sw.toString());

  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

In order to solve this in python you should understand the [Map and Tile Coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates) principles used by Google Maps JavaScript API and implement projection logic similar to Google Maps API in python.

Fortunately, somebody has already did this task and you can find the project that implements methods similar to `map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint()` and `map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng()` from my example in python. Have a look at this project in github:

https://github.com/hrldcpr/mercator.py

So, you can download mercator.py and use it in your project. My JavaScript API example converts into the following python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mercator import *

w = 200
h = 200
zoom = 16
lat = 53.4055429
lng = -2.9976502

centerPixel = get_lat_lng_tile(lat, lng, zoom)
pixelSize = pow(2, -zoom)

nePoint = (centerPixel[0] + w*pixelSize, centerPixel[1] - h*pixelSize)
swPoint = (centerPixel[0] - w*pixelSize, centerPixel[1] + h*pixelSize)

ne = get_tile_lat_lng(zoom, nePoint[0], nePoint[1]);
sw = get_tile_lat_lng(zoom, swPoint[0], swPoint[1]);

print 'NorthEast: ', ne
print 'SouthWest: ', sw
```

Comment: I am working on python, would it be python based api?

Comment: Your python results are definitely wrong, they differs from js results.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Thanks for the comment. I didn't test the mercator.py thoroughly, indeed, it is possible the implementation is not precise enough, but it demonstrates the idea. I will have a look once I have some free time.

Comment: I'm talking not about precision but about an error. The difference is huge, more than a factor of hundred.

Comment: Anyway, looks like the author forgot about his question)

Comment: I've found the difference between your results and correct ones. They differs by a factor of 512. `mercator` docs should have mentioned that one needs to specify the original width :) 
But I still don't see a need to use external library instead of cosines and powers. Good luck. Strange disappeared bounty.