# How to get the real bounding box in the static images API MAPBOX?

Tags: mapbox-api-staticimages

With the MAPBOX Static Images API is possible to download an static image. If I give a center coordinates, a zoom and the dimensions (in pixels) of the image the api returns the static image.

How can I get the real coordinates of the bounding box of the resulting image? Or, is possible to convert the pixels (width x height) of the image to meters to be able to calculate the coordinates of the bounding box?

Thanks

Comment: I've found the solution in the following link [Converting Pixels to LatLng Coordinates from google static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106276/converting-pixels-to-latlng-coordinates-from-google-static-image)