# Getting the GPS position of coordinates (x,y) on a Google maps API satellite image in function of the zoom level

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, gis

Using yolo to detect features on satellite images Google Maps API, I get the coordinates (x,y) of each features. The reference (0, 0) is the top left corner. Yolo provides also the width and height of the bounding box. I have the GPS position of the center of the image.

I would like to get the GPS coordinates for the center of each feature.

```
def getGPSPosition(centerLat, centerLong, zoomLevel, x, y):
  # calculate degrees per pixel ratio at the given zoom level
 degreesPerPixel = 180 / pow(2,zoomLevel);
 imageSize = 640
  
  # calculate offset in degrees
 deltaX = (x-imageSize/2) * degreesPerPixel
 deltaY = (y-imageSize/2) * degreesPerPixel
  
  # calculate gps position based on the center coordinates
 gpsLat = centerLat + deltaY
 gpsLong = centerLong + deltaX
 
 return (gpsLat, gpsLong)
```

I'm supposed to get the coordinate of the upper left corner of the bounding box. I miss the target... The result is approx 50m away from the correct point.

Answer (score 1):

try somethin like that. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243808/10809912) to understand the logic.

```
import math

def getGPSPosition(centerLat, centerLong, zoomLevel, x, y):
    dppx = 360 / math.pow(2, zoomLevel + 8)
    dppy = dppx * math.cos(centerLat * math.pi / 180)
    return centerLat - dppx * ( y - 640 / 2),centerLong + dppy * ( x  - 640 / 2)
```